# The Asset Browser and Posable Assets

Tags: armature, bones, pose-mode, curve-modifier, asset-browser

I can't seem to figure out a good workflow here so I wonder if someone with more experience could help.

I use Blender for product images. So I make extensive use of the asset browser because the products that I create often have several material variations (e.g. colour). I use linking (mostly) when dropping in an asset in from the browser, because when I update the original source mesh I want all my variations to update with the new mesh. All good so far.

The problem comes when I have something that is movable. So, for example, I do quite a few wristwatches and I want the straps to be moveable/posable so I can create different images. But of course, if I use a curve with the underlying strap object, the curve is inaccessible when the strap is used from the asset browser. Same if I use bones.

If, on the other hand, I just create an object (without any curves or bones) and mark that as an asset, then drop that asset into a scene and attempt to add a curve or bone at that point, that doesn't work either. A curve I can't add because assets don't have modifiers. Bones I CAN add but they appear to do nothing.

So can anyone tell me the best (or any) way to use 'posability' with assets dropped in from the asset browser? It may well be obvious to some, but sadly not to me :-)

Many thanks for reading.
Steve

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I figured it out.

I added a bendy bone to the source asset (the one in the asset browser). As I said in the question, this is inaccessible when I drop the asset into a scene, BUT if I override the object, the armature becomes accessible and I can pose the object.

It's not ideal because, as anyone who uses the asset browser will know, as soon as the object is overridden, it snaps back to its origin position and can't be moved. So I have to then create a new asset from this posed asset and use that in yet another scene (which is what I have to do anyway when creating versions with different materials). So it means I need a new asset for every colour/pose - nightmare!

What I would sorely love to do is pick an asset (that has an armature), drop it into a scene, then just pose it how I want. Feels like I'm missing something obvious.

So anyway it's all a bit long-winded, but at least I have a way forwards. I would still appreciate any better approaches if there are any.

Thanks
Steve